# How can i solve this error message in OpenERP or Odoo?

Tags: xml, runtime-error, odoo, helper

How can solved this error in OpenERP or Odoo ?
I'm trying to create an own demo data for a custom module but I don't kno how to do it.
I'm using Odoo 12 and the module is account.invoices

```
Error: Odoo Server Error Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 656, in
_handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 314, in
_handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 346, in
_call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/service/model.py", line 98, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 967, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 955, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 746, in
_call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)   File "<decorator-gen-67>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 627, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_module.py", line 561, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/modules/loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 802, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)   File "/home/ubuntu/OdooAddons/odoo/odoo/tools/convert.py", line 852, in convert_xml_import
    relaxng.assert_(doc)   File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3542, in lxml.etree._Validator.assert_ AssertionError: Element odoo has extra content: data, line 2
```

And I have this demo data code to create a new Invoice but I don't know how to resolve this error

```
<odoo>
    <data>
         <record id="emb_invoice_1" model="account.invoice">
            <field name="partner_id" ref="base.res_partner_2"/>
            <field name="user_id" ref="base.user_demo"/>
             <field name="origin">SO001</field>
            <field name="emb_dual_use">True</field>
            <field name="emb_message">True Field transport</field>
            <field name="amount_untaxed_invoice_signed">750.00</field>
            <field name="amount_tax_signed">157.50</field>
            <field name="amount_total_signed">907.50</field>
        </record>
        <record id="emb_invoice_line_ids" model="account.invoice">
            <field name="invoice_line_ids">
            <field name="order_id" ref="emb_invoice_1"/>
            <field name="product_id" ref="product.product">'{[FURN_0096] Customizable Desk (Steel, White)}'</field>
            <field name="name">'PC Assamble + 2GB RAM'</field>
            <field name="account_id">'162'</field>
            <field name="price_unit">'2950.00'</field>
            <field name="origin_country" model="res.country.state">'{Spain}'</field>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second data record:

The declared fields are not present in `account.invoice`, you need to replace it with correct model name `account.invoice.line`, remove `<field name="invoice_line_ids">` tag and set the value of `invoice_id`. Use `invoice_id` instead of `order_id`.

The `ref` attribute must be a valid external id. Find the external id of `FURN_0096` and replace the field tag as following (like you did with `partner_id` and `user_id`):

```
<field name="product_id" ref="the external id">
```

You can read in the documentation that if a ref attribute is provided, its value must be a valid [external id](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/glossary.html#term-external-id), which will be looked up and set as the field’s value.

Mostly for [Many2one](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.Many2one) and [Reference](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/reference/orm.html#odoo.fields.Reference) fields

You have also to use the same logic with the two last fields: `account_id` and `origin_country`.

Comment: I have this code now but I'm not sure how can I get the account_id external_id

Comment: `<record id="emb_invoice_line_2" model="account.invoice.line">
            <field name="invoice_id" ref="emb_invoice_1"/>
            <field name="product_id" ref="product.product_product_25_product_template"/>
            <field name="name">'PC Assamble + 2GB RAM'</field>
            <field name="account_id" ref="account.account_account_27_16907054"/>
            <field name="account_analytic_id" ref="account.analytic.account_analytic_account_27_16907054">SERV_89665: SO021</field>
       </record>`

Comment: The external id of the product is easy to get but the account_id I don't know how to do it

Comment: You can use the `search` attribute. In case of a relational field, the value should be a domain. You can use the following code to search for an account using its code: `<field name="account_id" search="[('code', '=', '200000')]"/>`

Comment: oh nice thank you! I have this question if you can help me with this one it will be very gratefull!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67420111/how-to-create-an-accordion-or-subcategories-view-in-openerp-or-odoo