# How to Create an accordion or subcategories view in OpenERP or Odoo?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, helper

Create an accordion or subcategories view?

I'm trying to create an accordion view from product.category view.

I want all the categories at top and if any of them have childs I want them in a accordion list or with subcategories.

For Example:

- All/Purchase/Chairs/C88

  - All

    - Purchase

      - Chairs

        - C88

I want this with the product categories

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Let's use the bootstrap accordion (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/), for instance : for products belonging to category_2 included in category_1 :

```
 <odoo>
 <template id="products_categories_nested_accordions" inherit_id="website_sale.products_categories" active="False" customize_show="True" name="eCommerce Categories">
 <xpath expr="//div[@id='products_grid_before']" position="inside">
            
 <a href="#" role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" t-attf-data-target=".#{category_1.name}" t-attf-data="#{category_1.name}" aria-expanded="false">
 <span class="fa fa-plus pull-right"/>
 <label t-field="category_1.name" />
 </a>
 <t t-foreach="category_1.categories_2_ids" t-as="category_2">
 <div t-attf-class=" collapse #{category_1.name} " 
 t-attf-data="#{category_2.name}" >     
 <a href="#" role="button" class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" t-attf-data-target=".#{category_2.name}" t-attf-data="#{category_2.name}" aria-expanded="false">
 <span class="fa fa-plus pull-right"/>
 <label t-field="category_2.name" />
 </a>
 </div>
 <t t-foreach="products" t-as="product">
 <div t-attf-class=" collapse #{category_2.name} " 
 t-attf-data="#{product.name}" >
<span itemprop="name" t-field="product.name" class="my-0" />
</div>
</t>
</t>
</xpath>
</template>
</odoo>
```

And so on with other nested categories in each other...

Comment: But this thing I can use in Odoo custom module into a view?

Comment: ...yes, by inheriting an existing view + using xpath: in an xml file inside your module OR in the view in the odoo Backoffice CONFIGURATION > Technicals > View  localhost:8069/web?debug=1#action=28&cids=1&id=8238&menu_id=4&model=ir.ui.view&view_type=form... See official tutorial to learn how to inherit a view : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/howtos/website.html?highlight=view#altering-existing-views

Comment: how can i fix it? @sylvain

Comment: ...In your xml file, you must add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>before wrtiting your code.... and after yourd code, write </odoo>

Comment: Let's have a look to the official modules in the addons directory...